# Difference between a Dynamic Web Application and a 'normal' Web application

Tags: web, dynamic, web-applications

For a project report I have this main question but I'm doubting if there is any difference between these two or is it just a naming convention, meaning they are the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name suggests. 
A dynamic web application generates the pages/data in real time, as per the request, a respective response will trigger from the server end and will reach the client end(your end). Depending upon the response the client side code will take action as it's supposed to.

**Example**:
On twitter when you click on follow. The button turns blue. In reality, when you click that button. You generate a request that is sent to the server. The server then generates a response. And with the response the button turns blue.

While in a normal web application or the simple website. There is no request, response scenario. All and all it's just a client end with some HTML with some CSS or maybe Javascript or any other extension of Javascript. No server end.

**Example:** https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/nntut.html